# ULX libraries for NI LabVIEW in Linux

Tags: linux, labview, chromebook, crouton-os

I have a Chromebook, and at my college we're doing some programming in LabVIEW. I have Crouton installed and know that I can install LabVIEW in Linux.

However, we also need the [ULX libraries](http://www.mccdaq.com/daq-software/universal-library-extensions-lv.aspx) for our project. It seems that these are only available for Windows. Is there any way that I can use them in Linux?

Comment: Before you start investing time in looking into the driver issue, have you actually successfully got LabVIEW running on your Chromebook? NI only supports certain Linux distributions, currently Red Hat Enterprise Linux Desktop + Workstation 6.5 or later, open SUSE 12.3 or 13.1, or Scientific Linux 6.5 or later (http://www.ni.com/labview/requirements/)

Comment: @nekomatic A quick Google search shows that some people claim to have gotten LabVIEW running on Ubuntu, but as you said it's not officially supported by NI. My class found out we need to use the 2014 version because the instructions we were given don't work in the 2015 version. The only student edition of LabVIEW currently available is 2015, so our professor had to give us a copy of his 2014 installation. Since my classmates had difficulties on Windows, I don't think I'm going to try installing LabVIEW on an unsupported Linux distro. At least someone in my lab group has it running now.

Comment: "the only student edition of LabVIEW currently available is 2015" - did anyone contact NI about this? A LabVIEW licence normally allows you to run older versions as well as the latest. For Windows you can just download the relevant version of LabVIEW and then activate it with whatever licence(s) you have, for Linux and Mac you'd need to get NI to send you the disc, but it'd certainly be worth asking.

Comment: I installed LabVIEW 2014 SP1 on my Windows 8.1 PC, and was indeed able to activate it with the student edition license. My lab group still uses my classmate's laptop to run LabVIEW in class, but I was able to program our project outside of class on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

While [some MCC devices work for Linux](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:p_qRIyZnWacJ:www.mccdaq.com/daq-software/Linux-Support.aspx+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) the intermediate layer between LabVIEW and MCC UL (the ULX) seems to be availalbe for Windows only.
However, nobody prevents you from porting UL functions to LabVIEW using [Import Library Wizard](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361L-01/lvexcodeconcepts/importing_shared_library/)

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm new to LabVIEW, I'm not sure how this would be done. I'm guessing that the MCC device I'm using would need to work with Linux, and I'd need to install a driver for it and import the needed UL functions. Is this correct?

Comment: You might also contact Measurement Computing directly and ask them if they're interested in helping you port those libraries. They might benefit from having their software in more places.